# Favicon causes mixed content warning over SSL

Tags: ssl

I have the following favicon loading via header.php:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wp-content/themes/themename/img/favicon.ico' ) ); ?>">
```

My site has an SSL certificate installed. Google Chrome loads the each page over SSL perfectly, but Firefox flags a mixed content warning. I can see via the source (both in Chrome and Firefox), that the favicon is being served via http.

I can't work out why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little more reading via the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Favicon), I discovered that I was calling the favicon incorrectly. It should be called like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

Using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` checks for SSL.